# how to change text color and back ground color of span when ng click function occur

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have two button. Today and tomorrow. And i have ng click function for both button. What i need is by default my button back ground color will be white. and text color will be red.

When i click my totday button , i need my back ground color to chnage to blue, and text color have to chnage to white.

and if i press tomorrow button this same design have to apply for this button. and my today button have to be default color. How to do this :

here my code :

```
<div class="row" style="height: 52px;">
    <div  class="col col-50" style="border-right: 1px #ccc solid; padding-top: 17px; text-align: center;" ng-click="GetDetails()" id="1">
      <span class="assertive" style="margin: 0px;color: #B90143;">TODAY</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top: 17px;text-align: center;" ng-click="GetTomorrowDetails()">

          <span class="assertive" style="margin: 0px;color: #B90143; width: 100%;">TOMORROW</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My controller for `ng-cilck` for both button :**

```
 $scope.GetDetails = function(){

     $ionicLoading.hide();
   $scope.orders.length = 0

    MydeliveryFactory.save($scope.orderInfo, function(response){
     var AllOrderValues = response.allorders;
        for (var i = AllOrderValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(AllOrderValues[i].dateAdded == todaydate && AllOrderValues[i].monthAdded == todayMonth ) {
              $scope.orders.push(AllOrderValues[i]);
               $ionicLoading.hide();
              console.log($scope.orders);

            } 
          } 
        $window.localStorage.setItem("MyDeliverYOrders", JSON.stringify($scope.orders));

    });
  }

$scope.GetTomorrowDetails = function(){
     $ionicLoading.show();
       $scope.orders.length = 0
    MydeliveryFactory.save($scope.orderInfo, function(response){
    var Allvalues = response.allorders;
        for (var i = Allvalues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(Allvalues[i].dateAdded == tomorrowdate && Allvalues[i].monthAdded == tomorrowMonth) {
              $scope.orders.push(Allvalues[i]);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
              console.log($scope.orders);
            } 
          } 
        $window.localStorage.setItem("MyDeliverYOrders", JSON.stringify($scope.orders));

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle classes with `ng-class` and `$scopes`.

I have added `ng-class="{'active':active.today}"` in button, it means `active` class will be added when `active.today` is `true` and will remove when `active.today` is `false`, same for tomorrow button,

and in `js` function is just toggling `$scope` between `true` and `false`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.active = {};
  $scope.GetDetails = function() {
    $scope.active.tomorrow = false;
    $scope.active.today = true;
  }

  $scope.GetTomorrowDetails = function() {
    $scope.active.today = false;
    $scope.active.tomorrow = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="row" style="height: 52px;">
  <div class="col col-50" style="border-right: 1px #ccc solid; padding-top: 17px; text-align: center;" ng-click="GetDetails()" id="1">
    <span class="assertive" ng-class="{'active':active.today}" style="margin: 0px;color: #B90143;">TODAY</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top: 17px;text-align: center;" ng-click="GetTomorrowDetails()">

    <span class="assertive" ng-class="{'active':active.tomorrow}" style="margin: 0px;color: #B90143; width: 100%;">TOMORROW</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but actually i am struck with where i have to put up ur code in my controller. Because if i put your code at staring then my full screen is blue and still activity indicator is loading and then slowly its showing the value.and then only its changing the bg color. I have updated my code in my question. Can u help me out.where i need to put ur code in my each controller method

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope this can help you to understand what is actually happening.

Comment: YES, but text color is not changing to white. I was give ur same code only but dont know why its not chnaging

Comment: You have given `inline css`, use `color:#fff!important` in active class to override `inline css`

Comment: That inline for default red color for text. But when we click that. the text color have o change to white color

Comment: Now I have used your HTML for demo, Check updated answer.

Comment: i have one problem now. That active css code is taking for all screen . Means that, if i redirect from one screen to another screen or if i press log out, of if i login,all the time my screen background color as `blue` and my text color as ` white`. why its applying for all tee screen ??

Comment: Maybe they have `active` class too, changing class name can help you, use `active_btn` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class to your button and provide them the default css.

```
<div class="row" style="height: 52px;">
    <div class="btn col col-50" style="border-right: 1px #ccc solid; padding-top: 17px; text-align: center;" ng-click="GetDetails($event)" id="1">
        <span class="assertive" style="margin: 0px;color: #B90143;">TODAY</span>
    </div>
    <div class="btn col col-50" style="padding-top: 17px;text-align: center;" ng-click="GetTomorrowDetails($event)">
        <span class="assertive" style="margin: 0px;color: #B90143; width: 100%;">TOMORROW</span>
    </div>
</div>

.btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}
```

And in your Controller, handle your click handlers:

```
$scope.GetDetails = function(event) {
  $scope.defaultColors();
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  event.target.style.color = "white";
};

$scope.GetTomorrowDetails = function(event) {
  $scope.defaultColors();
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  event.target.style.color = "white";
};

$scope.defaultColors = function() {
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("btn")).forEach(function(el, i) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      el.style.color = "red";
  });
};
```

Comment: thansk for your solution. i am getting error this line [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("btn")).forEach(el) {
    
      el.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      el.target.style.color = "red";
}
`

Comment: error is :controllers.js:530Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: yes i have edited my code. But still same error in same line

Comment: There was a brace missing, I have fixed it now. :)

Comment: I think now only extra brace are there. I also tried to fix that. But not able to find it out which one is making issue

Comment: @sinha The syntax errors have been removed. The code should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#!), using this you will be able to dynamically change the class assigned to your buttons.

Your button html could look a little like this:

```
<button ng-class="[btn, btn-primary, {today: active-class}]" ng-click="GetDetails()">Today</button>
<button ng-class="[btn, btn-primary, {!today: active-class}]" ng-click="GetTomorrowDetails()">Tomorrow</button>
```

You controller, something like this:

```
$scope.today = true;

$scope.GetDetails = function() {
    $scope.today = true;
}

$scope.GetTomorrowDetails = function() {
    $scope.today = false;
}
```

Comment: @B Miller here where i can specify my background color or text color ?

Comment: You would need to define a class in your css file, like: `active-class: { color: white; background-color: blue }`. The ngClass would then toggle the active-class on and off.